# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 1, 3, 3], expected input[32, 3, 224, 224] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to push images through a CNN, but I keep getting this error on both Windows 11 and Ubuntu Linux 22.04. I have seen similar errors posted on the internet but I cant seem to figure out why this is happening.

The answers I've seen on here dont seem to apply to my model, but most likely I am doing something very silly.

I am not sure why the model keeps thinking my grayscale images are RGB. Multiple methods have been used to confirm the grayscale images are in-fact grayscale.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 191, in <module>
    main_pt()
  File "main.py", line 101, in main_pt
    stats = pre_train_one_ep(ep, args, tb_lg, itrt_train, iters_train, model, optimizer)
  File "main.py", line 157, in pre_train_one_ep
    loss = model(inp, active_b1ff=None, vis=False)
  File "/global/common/software/nersc/shasta2105/pytorch/1.9.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 35, in forward
    return self.module(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/global/common/software/nersc/shasta2105/pytorch/1.9.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/global/cfs/cdirs/dune/www/data/2x2/simulation/silentc_work/SparK/SparK/SparK/pretrain/spark.py", line 96, in forward
    fea_bcffs: List[torch.Tensor] = self.sparse_encoder(masked_bchw)
  File "/global/common/software/nersc/shasta2105/pytorch/1.9.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/global/cfs/cdirs/dune/www/data/2x2/simulation/silentc_work/SparK/SparK/SparK/pretrain/encoder.py", line 208, in forward
    return self.sp_cnn(x, hierarchical=True)
  File "/global/common/software/nersc/shasta2105/pytorch/1.9.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/global/cfs/cdirs/dune/www/data/2x2/simulation/silentc_work/SparK/SparK/SparK/pretrain/models/custom.py", line 42, in forward
    x = self.conv1(inp_bchw)
  File "/global/common/software/nersc/shasta2105/pytorch/1.9.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/global/cfs/cdirs/dune/www/data/2x2/simulation/silentc_work/SparK/SparK/SparK/pretrain/encoder.py", line 21, in sp_conv_forward
    x = super(type(self), self).forward(x)
  File "/global/common/software/nersc/shasta2105/pytorch/1.9.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 443, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "/global/common/software/nersc/shasta2105/pytorch/1.9.0/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 439, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [32, 1, 3, 3], expected input[32, 3, 224, 224] to have 1 channels, but got 3 channels instead
```

My model architecture is

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from typing import List
from timm.models.registry import register_model


class YourConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=1, global_pool='avg'):
        super(YourConvNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.maxpool1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, padding=0)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
        self.maxpool2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, padding=0)

    def get_downsample_ratio(self) -> int:
        # Define the downsampling ratio
        return 4  # Update this based on your actual architecture

    def get_feature_map_channels(self) -> List[int]:
        # Define the number of channels of each feature map
        return [32, 64]  # for conv1 and conv2

    def forward(self, inp_bchw: torch.Tensor, hierarchical=False):
        """
        The forward with `hierarchical=True` would ONLY be used in `SparseEncoder.forward` (see `pretrain/encoder.py`).

        :param inp_bchw: input image tensor, shape: (batch_size, channels, height, width).
        :param hierarchical: return the logits (not hierarchical), or the feature maps (hierarchical).
        :return:
            - hierarchical == False: return the logits of the classification task, shape: (batch_size, num_classes).
            - hierarchical == True: return a list of all feature maps, which should have the same length as the return value of `get_feature_map_channels`.
              E.g., for the provided ConvNet, it should return a list [1st_feat_map, 2nd_feat_map].
                    for an input size, the shapes could be [(B, 32, 56, 56), (B, 64, 28, 28)] based on provided architecture.
        """
        x = self.conv1(inp_bchw)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.maxpool1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.maxpool2(x)

        # Depending on the hierarchical flag, return feature maps or logits
        if hierarchical:
            # Return feature maps
            #return [(1, 64, 12, 12)]  # Update this based on your actual architecture
            return [(1, 64, 54, 54)]
        else:
            # Perform further operations for classification logits, if needed
            # Example: Flatten x and add fully connected layers
            return x


@register_model
def your_convnet_small(pretrained=False, **kwargs):
    return YourConvNet(**kwargs)

@register_model
def your_cnn(pretrained=False, **kwargs):
    return YourConvNet(**kwargs)


@torch.no_grad()
def convnet_test():
    from timm.models import create_model
    cnn = create_model('your_convnet_small')
    print('get_downsample_ratio:', cnn.get_downsample_ratio())
    print('get_feature_map_channels:', cnn.get_feature_map_channels())


    downsample_ratio = cnn.get_downsample_ratio()
    feature_map_channels = cnn.get_feature_map_channels()
    
    # check the forward function
    B, C, H, W = 4, 1, 224, 224
    inp = torch.rand(B, C, H, W)
    feats = cnn(inp, hierarchical=True)
    assert isinstance(feats, list)
    assert len(feats) == len(feature_map_channels)
    print([tuple(t.shape) for t in feats])
    
    # check the downsample ratio
    feats = cnn(inp, hierarchical=True)
    assert feats[-1].shape[-2] == H // downsample_ratio
    assert feats[-1].shape[-1] == W // downsample_ratio
    
    # check the channel number
    for feat, ch in zip(feats, feature_map_channels):
        assert feat.ndim == 4
        assert feat.shape[1] == ch


if __name__ == '__main__':
    convnet_test()
```

Comment: The model is not expecting 3 channels, the input received has 3 channels where 1 is expected. I would take a thorough look at how you supply the input data to see why that could be the case.

Comment: Oh! Yes you're right. I am simply pointing the model to a folder that has grayscale images. From my understanding x = self.conv1(inp_bchw) should be the first layer after input. Hmm

Comment: Are you sure the images are grayscale and not just RGB(A)? You might want to try using [```torchvisions.transforms.Grayscale```](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.Grayscale.html).

Comment: Yes. That worked. Thank you!